# camel propertyplaceholder environment specific file

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using apache camel 2.15.1 , I have three properties files which are environment specific in classpath like `myprop.properties, myprop-enva.properties, myprop-envb.properties.` 
I'm using propertyplaceholder in camelcontext, I am able to load myprop.properties.

I don't know how to load myprop-enva.properties when websphere env.prop= _enva

My current config looks like this..

```
    <propertyPlaceholder location="classpath:myprop.properties" //Here I need to modify to make it work
        id="placeholder1" />
```

I tried changing as `location="classpath:myprop${env.prop}.properties"` but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use blueprint property placeholder, then environment specific cfg file will be loaded from the server. Different server - different cfg file.

Or you can put specific property file into the bundle on package phase (using maven profiles).

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <env>production</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>developer</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <env>developer</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>props/**/*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/props/${env}</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ..........
</build>
```

Comment: Currently we use spring with camel ,not sure i can use blueprint along with spring. second option won't work for me because it breaks deployment team guidelines (in my project).. Thanks for the solutions @Alelxey

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the locations of your properties files, and add the ignore option, then Camel will skip files that are not there. And in the location you can refer to an ENV name.

See more details in the Camel docs

- http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html